# How to create DSL in Scala for command lines with minimum extra boilerplate

Tags: scala, dsl

I need to develop an API for users not familiar with scala (neither Java) but familiar with Shell. They will, basically write shell scripts inside a scala class (I know I could just call external shell scripts, but come on! Also, later we will have some functions for common shell tasks).

I was hoping to accomplish something like:

```
1 object MyCoolScript extends MyMagicTrait {
2   $ "mkdir /tmp/test"
3   $ "cd /tmp/test"
4   $ "wget some-url"   
5 }
```

Being more direct, how can I turn lines 2-4 (or a possibly less concise version) into Seq[String] that I could process in MyMagicTrait?

I know about *sys.process.stringToProcess* but if I have:

```
object MyCoolScript extends MyMagicTrait {
  "mkdir /tmp/test" !!
  "cd /tmp/test" !!
  "wget some-url" !!  
}
```

How can I get the result of each command in a concise way? also, I was hoping for a $ "xxx" notation.

Post Answers Update:

Thanks to @debilski, @tenshi and @daniel-c-sobral I was able to come up a very close to the desired implementation: https://gist.github.com/2777994

Comment: I like it when we get line numbers in code. It's so hard to count to 5! And it keeps my sed-experience always fresh.

Comment: I did that because I was referring to lines 2-4. Don't see the use for sed now :).

Comment: By the way, DO NOT USE `$`. You can write code using it, but it is not legal code, and it may break without notice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems that string interpolation that comes with Scala 2.10 can help you here. At first you can implement simple `$` method, that simply executes command immediately. In order to make it you need to add this custom method on `StringContext`:

```
object ShellSupport {
    implicit class ShellStrings(sc: StringContext) {
        def $(args: Any*) = 
            sc.s(args: _*) split "\n" map (_.trim) filterNot (_.isEmpty) foreach { cmd =>
                // your excution logic goes here
                println(s"Executing: $cmd")
            }

    }
}
```

Now you can use it like this:

```
import ShellSupport._

val testDir = "/tmp/test"

$"mkdir $testDir"
$"cd $testDir" 
$"""
    wget some-url
    wget another-url
 """
```

You can take advantage of it's syntax (it's only downside, is that you can't add space between `$` and `"`) and string interpolation within command.

---

Now let's try to implement your magic trait. It's generally the same idea, but I'm also using `DelayedInit` in order to properly define commands and then automatically execute them during class creation.

```
trait MyMagicTrait extends DelayedInit {
    private var cmds: List[String] = Nil

    def commands = cmds

    implicit class ShellStrings(sc: StringContext) {
        def $(args: Any*) = {
            val newCmds = sc.s(args: _*) split "\n" map (_.trim) filterNot (_.isEmpty)
            cmds = cmds ++ newCmds
        }
    }

    def delayedInit(x: => Unit) {
        // your excution logic goes here
        x
        cmds map ("Excutintg: " + _) foreach println
    }
}
```

And it's usage:

```
class MyCoolScript extends MyMagicTrait {
  val downloader = "wget"

  $"mkdir /tmp/test"
  $"cd /tmp/test" 
  $"""
    $downloader some-url
    $downloader another-url
   """ 
}

new MyCoolScript
```

Both of these solutions produce the same output:

```
Executing: mkdir /tmp/test
Executing: cd /tmp/test
Executing: wget some-url
Executing: wget another-url
```

Answer (score 5):

```
class Shell {
  var elems = Vector[String]()
  def >(str: String) = elems :+= str

  def run() = elems.map( whatever )
}

val shell = new Shell

shell> "mkdir /tmp/test.dir"
shell> "cd /tmp/test.dir"
```

Comment: Now we are talking! If I call $ instead of shell, I have $> "". Now I just need a way of applying that automatically. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This is just riffing on @Debilski's and @Tomasz's ideas to show you can combine them nicely:

```
trait Magic {
  object shell {
    var lines = IndexedSeq[String]()
    def >(xs: String) { lines ++= xs.split("\n").map(_.trim) }
  }
  def doSomethingWithCommands { shell.lines foreach println }
}

object MyCoolScript extends App with Magic {
  println("this is Scala")

  shell> """
    mkdir /tmp/test
    cd /tmp/test
  """

  doSomethingWithCommands

  shell> """
    wget some-url
  """
}
```

I don't really see how you could get any less boilerplate if you want to combine shell with Scala commands, since you need something to show where shell is beginning and ending.

Answer (score 2):

## Dummy approach

```
class Shell(commands: String) {
    commands.lines foreach {
        command =>
            //run your command
    }
}

class MyCoolScript extends Shell("""

    mkdir /tmp/test
    cd /tmp/test
    wget some-url

""")
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that I cannot have scala statements between command lines or as part of them. Maybe scala's 2.10 string interpolation can help me with that. Still I was hopping for a better solution. Thanks.

Comment: @JhonnyEverson: I am hoping for a better solutions as well :-).

Answer (score 2):

These results are all over the place. Alas, I don't think sys.process will suffice for you. Let's first write out that example, in such a way that it does what you asked for:

```
val result = (
    "mkdir /tmp/test ###
    "cd /tmp/test" ###
    "wget someurl
).lines_!
```

Now, why it doesn't work:

First, `cd` will throw an exception -- there's no `cd` executable. That's an internal shell command, so only shell can execute it.

Next, assuming `cd` would work, the `wget` would *not* happen at `/tmp/test`. Each of the commands above is executed anew in Java's current working directory. You can specify the directory in which each command is to be executed, but you can't have a CWD (it's not "mutable").

Comment: I was not sure about it but I had that in mind. I was thinking of doing the necessary adjustments for the commands to work.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**

I would do this:

```
res = List("mkdir /tmp/test", "cd /tmp/test", "wget some-url").map(_!!)
// res is a List[String] of the output of your commands
```

You can execute system commands like so:

```
scala> import scala.sys.process._
import scala.sys.process._

scala> "pwd"!
/Users/kgann
res0: Int = 0
```

You should be able to wrap this into a DSL but it's already pretty terse.

Comment: Thanks but I know that, my question is how can I can group lines of Strings and turn them into a List so I could process them. I need to get the result of each process

Comment: The problem with this solution is that the scripts will quickly become unreadable. I'm talking about 10-50 lines of script.  I guess I could  use one line + comma for the elements of the List, but that's not very clean.